# Sorting a TreeMap by object properties

Tags: java, dictionary, sorting, comparator, treemap

I have a TreeMap full of Houses. Each house has different properties such as address, number of floors, etc. The TreeMap gets populated into a JList so that the user can select a house from the list, and then view each property in its own respective field. Before the list is open, the user has the option to sort by various different ways such as House addresses alphabetically, or by highest number of bedrooms etc and then they will view the list of Houses in that order.

I understand that TreeMaps are sorted by their keys. I am trying to use Comparator but I feel like I've hit a wall and I have no idea if I'm doing this correctly. How can I call my Comparator from the JFrame/JList that I am using?

Can anyone help me out please? My instructor hasn't responded to my email in 4 days so I am stuck.

```
public static Map<String, House> neighborhood;

public Neighborhood(){
neighborhood = new TreeMap<>();
}

    public static class SortByAddress implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, House>>{
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry<String, House> o1, Entry<String, House> o2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return o1.getValue().getAddress().toString().compareTo(o2.getValue().getAddress().toString());
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Your comparator looks fine. Where's the map?

Comment: Why exactly are you using a `TreeMap`, nothing in question suggests that you are getting a house by some key? Seems to me like you need `TreeSet`, if you want to keep everything sorted, or just a `List` to be sorted every time the sort property changes.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry I've updated my code to show my map. It's in my Neighborhood class constructor. Both my map and my Comparator are in the same class.

Comment: @chaosfire I would love to use a List as I believe that would be the simplest thing to do, but as of right now I am under the assumption I need to use a map since in his demo he mentions Hashmap. I've asked my instructor if we are allowed to use a list, but no response yet.

Comment: Actually, your comparator doesn't make sense. You're comparing values instead of keys. And the type should be the same as the key type, not `Entry`. If you need to sort by value, `TreeMap` is the wrong data structure.

Comment: Well, as you already know `TreeMap` is sorted by the keys, your comparator will work only for `TreeMap<Map.Entry<String, House>, Something>`. I doubt that's what you need. Even if you can't get in touch with your instructor, you should be aware what you will be doing with those `House`s - we need this information in order to help you choose the correct structure. If you don't need quick access by some property - you won't be using `neighborhood.get(mappedProperty)`, then you should not use a `Map` (the exact implementation, TreeMap/HashMap/etc, does not matter).

Comment: This sounds like you might not even want a `Map`, but just a `List` that you sort with `Collections.sort`.

Comment: @chaosfire I think that's why I am stuck... It just doesn't make sense to use a Map. I watched his demo video again and he does specifically say the objects are in a HashMap. I think I'm just going to try to move all of the Objects in my HashMap into a List so technically they're still in a HashMap, but I'd be sorting it elsewhere.

Comment: What are the keys to your map?  Are they the addresses?  Or do you intend to build different maps with different keys, depending on the sort order?

Answer (score 0):

You only care about the values of your map, the `House` objects. So extract.

```
Collection < House > houses = myMap().values() ;
```

Make a sortable list from that collection.

```
List < House > housesSorted = new ArrayList<>( houses );
```

Define your various comparators.

```
Comparator < House > compareByBedroomCount = Comparator.comparing( House :: bedroomCount ) ;
Comparator < House > compareBySquareMeters = Comparator.comparing( House :: squareMeters ) ;
```

Apply the appropriate comparator.

```
housesSorted.sort( compareByBedroomCount );
```